# Can't remove border color from active list item in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am having trouble removing the border from my active list item in the navbar. See the attached photo. This is appearing only when I click the list item to reveal the dropdown then click it again which closes the dropdown. Then when i move the cursor off the list item it shows this blue border.

Any help would be appreciated. Note am using Less.

[image]

```
<div class="nav-collapse pull-right">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">DROPDOWN<b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
              <li><a href="#">PLANS</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">PLANS</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">PLANS</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li></ul>
```

Comment: I believe the LI elememt that has the class 'dropdown' on it get the class 'open' added to it when you activate the dropdown. Try using that 'open' class to turn the border off.

Comment: Sweet! Thanks Billy. I added it to the UL class and it did the trick. Many thanks.

Comment: Cool I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the LI elememt that has the class 'dropdown' on it get the class 'open' added to it when you activate the dropdown. Try using that 'open' class to turn the border off.

Answer (score 1):

Using the same markup above with the following style will remove the blue border
from the link.

`.dropdown a {
    outline: none;
}`